# distinguish between session timeout and session explicit (programmatic) invalidation

Tags: servlets, httpsession

I have an [HttpSessionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html). Is there a way, inside its [sessionDestroyed](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed-javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent-) method to distinguish between the following cases:

- the session was destroyed because the `session-timeout` configured in the web.xml was exceeded
- the session was destroyed programmatically by the the application calling [HttpSession#invalidate](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate--)

My use case is that I have a Single Sign On (SSO) arrangement between a number of applications and I want a global single sign off when one of the applications participating in the SSO arrangement explicitly logs off but not when its session times out, hence the need to distinguish between the two cases. I guess a way would be for the application to set some flag in the session object just prior to calling [HttpSession#invalidate](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate--). The [HttpSessionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) would then examine the session object and if that flag is found it would know this was a programmatic logout. If not, it was a container logout. Would that make sense and / or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`HttpSession#getLastAccessedTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getLastAccessedTime--) to obtain the timestamp of the last request sent by the client associated with the session. Then you can just do the math with help of [`HttpSession#getMaxInactiveInterval()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval--) and the current timestamp.

```
long lastAccessedTime = session.getLastAccessedTime();
long timeoutInMillis = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(session.getMaxInactiveInterval());
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

boolean sessionHasBeenTimedout = (now - timeoutInMillis > lastAccessedTime);
// ...
```